FastAPI lifespan event download model across multple gunicorn workers
I want to load a ML model to a local folder. However, I'm using gunicorn with multiple workers, so on startup each of them downloads the model:
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    model_path = os.path.join("./models", model)
    if os.path.isdir(model_path):
        print(f"Startup: model {model} exists, skip download")
    else:
        print(f"Startup: install model {model}")
        download_model(model)
    yield
    print('release models')

This leads to every worker downloading the model. Once it's downloaded it's skipped as expected.
Can a worker somehow "wait" for a few seconds until a folder exists or something? I don't want to introduce redis or another db just for this use-case as it's otherwise a really simple (stateless) app.

I think you can use file lock for this reason. The worker which opened and locked a file should download the model. Others should wait

I got it working by using the uvicorn-gunicorn-docker, which comes with a prestart.sh launcher.
For setups without Docker it is very useful to look into the image's entrypoint file.
It allows to place a prestart.sh script in the app's folder that is automatically detected.
I therefore added another python file install.py which runs the installation:
model = "medium"
# ./models directory is persisted via Docker volumes
model_path = os.path.join("./models", model)

if os.path.isdir(model_path):
    print(f"Startup: model {model} exists, skip download")
else:
    print(f"Startup: install model {model}")
    download_model(model)

and simply call it in the prestart.sh:
#! /usr/bin/env bash
python3 -m install

It is blocking the startup of all workers until the script is done.
